# Dynamically changing src url of static files

Tags: javascript, angular7

In our angular application we need to redirect to help page(given by documentation team) on click of help icon. Since we have hosted application using reverse proxy url of application changes based on deployment. example: https://stackoverflow.com/******/dashboard.. here path parameter changes everytime..

We have hoisted statically help page(all js/css/images files added to asset folder)
Since url is changing based on deployment, these static files are path also changes. eg)https://stackoverflow.com/******/asset/js/xx.js

Using window.location.pathname, we can find this variable and and replace ******
Since help page is created from tool, all these javascript, css and images path has to changed

`<script id="base.js" type="text/javascript" src="js/base.js"></script>`

This line has to changed to

`<script id="base.js" type="text/javascript" src="******/assets/js/base.js"></script>`

Instead of doing this manually for all files.. Is there any way i can dynamically change this? 
Or Append window.nodeName to this src something like below code

`window.nodeName = window.location.pathname === '/' ? '' : window.location.pathname;`

`<script id="base.js" type="text/javascript" src=window.nodeName+"/assets/js/base.js"></script>`